# AngularJs Select all attributed for an element

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-selectors

Can someone advise how I can search for an attribute of a selector that matches a query in AngularJS.

I have tried to following...

```
//1st Attempt
angular.element("editor-for[editor-title*='" + query + "']")
.each(function (index, value) {
}

//2nd Attempt
angular.element('editor-for:contains(' + query + ')')
.each(function (index, value) {
}
```

Below is the element printed to the console ...

```
 <editor-for ng-model="merchant.header.logos.smallAbsoluteUrl" is-required="true" data-width="88" data-height="31" editor-title="Logo Url" editor-type="image" is-disabled="!isMasterSector" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty" style=""></editor-for>
```

My goal is to search for any elements where 'editor-title' matches the query.

I suspect the second attempt doesn't work due to Angular using JQuery Lite. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your code it's not working due to the wrong ' char in your query: CSS is not able to handle ' chars as string delimiters.

Replace it this way:

```
angular.element("editor-for[editor-title*=\"" + query + "\"]")
```

Remember: only use double qoutes ( " ) in CSS as string delimiters.

Comment: I've changed to your following and this still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Are you sure you need the  * token too?

Comment: I've updated my question to show the element id like to select and also the second method I tried that also did not work.